# Complies and Build tests under different commands using Gradle

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

I am trying to do a POC for making a different directory approach for keeping unit, integration acceptance test, etc. I have seen many blogs where people creates folder along with main and test, but my intention is not to segregate but to consolidate those under the **test** folder itself. Like to know your views on this approach, I'm not sure if this has any pitfalls

For the above scenario, I have created three folders under the **test** folder in my spring boot application like as shown below for keeping unit test, integration test, and acceptance test.

My Gradle configuration is like as shown below

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs += ['src/test/integration/java', 'src/test/unit/java', 'src/test/acceptance/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs += ['src/test/integration/resources', 'src/test/unit/resources', 'src/test/acceptance/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

The above configuration is working fine, the only problem is I don't know how we can comply and build the files using

```
./gradle test -----------> builds unit, integration, acceptance tests & generates report 
./gradle unit -----------> builds only unit tests & generates report
./gradle integration ----> builds only integration tests & generates report
./gradle acceptance -----> builds only acceptance tests & generates report
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made `gradle` configurations for both cases: segregated and consolidated tests. You can see that in the case of consolidated tests the config is pretty simple, and `classpath` is always one `src/test/java`, and this approach provides a fairly simple human understanding of where the tests are located, for segregated tests the config is complicated and requires fine tuning, can arise classes and resources conflicts if no tests name patterns, and that case has the critical meaning for which type of writing tests you will chose.

This is configuration for multi test folders:

```xml
configurations {
    integrationImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    integrationRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)

    unitRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)
    unitImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
}

sourceSets {
    integration {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test/integration/java')
        }
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/integration/resources')
        }
    }

    unit {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test/unit/java')
        }
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/unit/resources')
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testClassesDirs += sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs
    testClassesDirs += sourceSets.unit.output.classesDirs
    classpath += sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    classpath += sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath
    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: $descriptor")
    }

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}

task integration(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testClassesDirs += sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs
    classpath += sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: $descriptor")
    }

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}

task unit(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.unit.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath
    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: $descriptor")
    }

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}
```

In case you have a single folder for all test types, your configuration will be:

```xml
task integrationSingleFolder(type: Test) {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*IT"
    }

    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}

task unitSingleFolder(type: Test) {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*Test"
    }

    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any way in which we can move those few duplicate codes to a common function and call it in integration, unit tasks. Does gradle provides anything similar

Comment: also like to know why you have given `events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"` explicitly

Comment: @AlexMan ```testLogging``` - allows configuring the logging of the test execution, property ```events``` adds status of executed test example ```TestClass > testMethod() PASSED``` or ```TestClass > testMethod() FAILED```

Comment: @AlexMan I will try to optimize configuration for avoiding code duplicates

Comment: did you get how to optimize configuration for avoiding code duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can create new gradle tasks in your `build.gradle` extending from original `test` task and configure respective src and resource dirs. Something like this

```
task unit(type: Test) {
  // your configuration
  include 'org/foo/unit/**'
}
```

and make `test.DependsOn(unit)` to execute with `test` task.

Comment: I tried that, but don't know what to provide for `testClassesDirs` and `classpath`. I gave `testClassesDirs = sourceSets.unit.output.classesDirs
classpath = sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath` but didn't work

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: can you please try `include`? Updated example above. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:includes

Comment: I tried that but did'nt work, i have given it like `include 'src/test/unit/**'` , looks like does it accept only package level